# Passing data to template and returning rendered result

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've read the documentation and search forums about CodeIgniter, but found no answers where this is possible or not.

I'm wondering if it's ever possible to pass value to a view process it and return it's values. If it's possible how? If not what are the alternatives? Basically, I'm trying to make my navbar dynamic. Thanks in advance.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Faculty extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data1['navbar'] = $this->_navbar(1);
        $data['nav'] = $this->load->view('layouts/nav', $data1, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('Facultypage', $data);
    }

    function _navbar($i) {
        $activebar = array('', '', '', '', '');
        $activebar[$i] = 'active';
        return $activebar;
    }
}
```

The template for navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navmargin" id="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logohelper" href="Home"><img class="logo" src="assets/images/jilcs-logo.jpg" alt="JILCS LOGO"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-helper" id="navlist">
                <li class="<?=$navbar[0];?>"><a href="index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class="<?=$navbar[1];?>" id="faculty"><a href="Faculty">Faculty</a></li>
                <li class="<?=$navbar[2];?>" id="enroll"><a href="Enroll">Enroll</a></li>
                <li class="<?=$navbar[3];?>" id="news"><a href="News">News</a></li>
                <li class="<?=$navbar[4];?>" id="about"><a href="About">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome in SO, Codeigniter simple takes load view 2nd param as array and you can use those array keys as php variable in your views..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file directly can set active class based on controller followed by method name,

Example: 
          `$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
          $thi->uri->segment(2); // method  and etc..`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-helper" id="navlist">
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='' ) { echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='Faculty') { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="faculty"><a href="Faculty">Faculty</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='Enroll') { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="enroll"><a href="Enroll">Enroll</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='News') { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="news"><a href="News">News</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=='About us') { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="about"><a href="About">About us</a></li>
```